# BASH variables in SFDX breaking dot notation in queries

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

With the most recent update to SFDX CLI, I've noticed that my queries that use dot notation in the select now retrieve null for dot notation columns if I use a bash variable.  It's really quite annoying.  Anybody else seeing this issue or have a workaround?

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set a variable
startdate=`sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "Select createddate from SetupAuditTrail order by createddate desc limit 1" -r csv | tail -n +2` 
#query using that variable
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "Select id,lastmodifiedby.name from apexclass where lastmodifieddate>$startdate"
```

It actually works, renders the variable correctly, you get the right rows.  But the dot notation column is returned as null.  Do the same query again without the variable and it works just fine.

Comment: Probably going to want to report this as a bug in either the github repo or the success community. Dont think theres any PM's for SFDX watching this tag.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you specify a static literal for `LastModifiedDate`? SFDX shouldn't be able to tell that a shell interpolation took place at all.

Comment: Also, what's your SFDX version number? I cannot reproduce in `6.15.0-ded9afdffb`

Comment: @DavidReed, I'm on the same build as you are.  It's not the variable--tried testing with just a static datetime. I've dug in deeper and it's even more bizarre that initially thought.  I get null if my results are less than 100.  I get [object] [object] for some range above 100 to less than 300 or so? And then any query where I return MORE than that, works just fine.

Comment: Needless to say, I've opened a case--will report back findings.  @battery.cord, do you have the link to their github repo?  I was not able to find it and am not confident support will understand this one.

Comment: Think I was thinking of the [dreamhouse example repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-dreamhouse), I dont see a sfdx master project under their github. Shame since it would be easy to report bugs that way. Definitely cross-post to the success community, I know PMs are active in it, and including the case number might help it get bumped along to someone who can do something about it.